# Getting a sorted uniq list of loggedin users with pipes

Tags: linux, pipe

I am trying to figure out how to get a list of logged in users and then with pipes sorting this list and only show every unique occurence.

I am almost there but the problem is that the "who-command" doesnt seem to allow to list just the user by name - it lists others parameters such as logintime, threads and so on. That results in making every every line unique.

here is my command

```
who | sort | uniq
```

and the result:

```
eric     :3           2014-09-25 15:23 (:3)
karen    :0           2014-09-25 14:41 (:0)
karen    pts/0        2014-09-25 14:48 (:0)
john     :2           2014-09-25 15:23 (:2)
carol    :1           2014-09-25 15:22 (:1)
carol    pts/25       2014-09-25 15:22 (:1)
admin    :4           2014-09-25 15:23 (:4)
```

So - how do I get a list of only the unique names in a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the first column only:

```
who | cut -d ' ' -f 1 | sort -u
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use:

```
who | awk '{print $1}' | sort | uniq
```

But there is more than one solution:

- [How to get the first column of every line from a CSV file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11668621/bash-script-get-the-first-column-of-every-line-in-a-csv-file)
- [bash: shortest way to get n-th column of output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7315587/bash-shortest-way-to-get-n-th-column-of-output)