# awking for nth column in csv

Tags: bash, csv, awk, terminal

Made a file.csv. There are 3 lines.

```
"ip","count","filename"
"1.1.1.1","57","somefilename1"
"2.2.2.2","30","2somefilename-2"
```

Tryed to awk for $3 so it should just list the 3rd column.

I tried a couple of methods:

```
awk '{print $3}' filename.csv
```

Output is blank, I was expecting just the 3rd column

Tried:

awk '{print $1}' filename.csv

Shows the full document instead of just the 1st column, nothing got filtered.

I searched stackoverflow and tried a few other methods. But for some reason I either get the full row or nothing.

What am I missing sounds simple enough

Comment: `awk -v FS=","  '{print $3}' filename.csv` You need to tell `awk` what to use as field seprator(`FS`) . By default its white space.

Comment: The default field delimiter in Awk is a sequence of whitespace. You are missing `awk -F,` to use comma instead. Voting to close as trivial typo.

Comment: Your input file has unicode quotes(`”`) and not ascii quotes(`"`), did you copy paste this file from a DOS editor? (windows - notepad/notepad++)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the first column of every line from a CSV file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11668621/how-to-get-the-first-column-of-every-line-from-a-csv-file)

Comment: @PS Thanks that was it. Does the S in FS allow you to use a string or something longer than 1 non-spaced comma as a separator?

Comment: @chowpay you can use string as `FS` but be careful. Also, best way to find out is to try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use -F as for "field-separator", you can find this at the man page of awk, like this:

```
awk -F, '{print $3}' Input_file
”filename”
”somefilename1”
”2somefilename-2”
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `,` as field separator:

```
awk -F ',' '{print $3}' filename.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

Following `awk` solutions may help you in same.
If you want to get output with `"` then following may help:

```
awk -F, '{print $3}'  Input_file
```

In case you need values of 3rd column without `"` then following may help you:

```
awk -F',|"' '{print $(NF-1)}'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

By default `awk` uses space as field separator, as described in the other posts you need to configure `,` as field separator otherwise the whole line will be treated as one field. To do this you can choose between the following 2 syntax:

```
awk -F',' '{print $3}' input.csv #to avoid bad surprises with you shell trying to interpret your field separator put it between simple quotes.
```

or you can also defined in the BEGIN clause, or at any point during the execution using the following syntax:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=","}{print $3}' input.csv
```